# creating python pop function for sqlite3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a pop function getting a row of data from a sqlite database and deleting that same row. I would like to not have to create an ID column so I am using ROWID. I want to always get the first row and return it. This is the code I have:

```html
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("Test.db")
c=db.cursor()
def sqlpop():
     c.execute("SELECT * from DATA WHERE ROWID=1")
     data = c.fetchall()
     c.execute("DELETE from DATA WHERE ROWID=1")
     db.commit()
     return(data)
```

when I call the function it gets the first item correctly, but after the first call the function returns nothing. like this:

```html
>>> sqlpop()
[(1603216325, 'placeholder IP line 124', 'placeholder Device line 124', '1,2,0', 1528, 1564)]
>>> sqlpop()
[]
>>> sqlpop()
[]
>>> sqlpop()
[]
```

what do I need to change for this function to work correctly?

update:
using what Schwern said I got the funtion to work:

```html
def sqlpop():
    c.execute("SELECT * from DATA ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1")
    data = c.fetchone()
    c.execute("DELETE from DATA ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1")
    db.commit()
    return data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`rowid`](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) is not the row order, it is a unique identifier for the row created by SQLite [unless you say otherwise](https://sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).

SQL rows have no inherent order. You could grab just one row...

```
select * from table limit 1;
```

But you'll get them in no guaranteed order. And without a rowid you have no way to identify it again to delete it.

If you want to get the "first" row you must define what "first" means. To do that you need something to order by. For example, a timestamp. Or perhaps [an auto-incrementing integer](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). You cannot use `rowid`, rowids are not guaranteed to be assigned in any particular order.

```
select *
from table
where created_at = max(created_at)
limit 1
```

So long as `created_at` is indexed, that should work fine. Then delete by its `rowid`.

You also don't need to use `fetchall` to fetch one row, use `fetchone`. In general, `fetchall` should be avoided as it risks consuming all your memory by slurping all the data in at once. Instead, use iterators.

```
for row in c.execute(...)
```

Comment: sorry I mentioned first because it is just easier to think that way for me. As long as the row that is deleted is the same as the row that is read I am happy, the order doesn't matter for me because I just want to empty out the database.

Comment: All the rows have a timestamp so I think I can get the smallest value in the timestamp column

Comment: @user169808 If you want to empty the table while reading its rows it would be much more efficient to lock the table, select all rows, iterate through them one by one as I mentioned at the end of the answer, then `delete from table` to remove all rows and `vacuum` to recover the space.